# Copy files to destination with a backup - batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

I am in need to a batch command, which will keep a backup of the files after copying to the destination.

Assume I have 2 files in source directory:

```
"1.txt" which has content (abc)  
"2.txt" which has content (abc)
```

and I have 4 files in Destination Directory:

```
"1.txt" which has content (xyz)  
"2.txt" which has content (xyz)  
"5.txt" which has content (xyz)  
"6.txt" which has content (xyz)
```

Now i have to copy all text files from source directory to destination directory, but in this case since the destination directory has two text files already present(1.txt and 2.txt) we need to take a backup of it before copying from source folder (maybe something like 1.txt.bkup 2.txt.bkup).

After copying from source to destination, contents of my destination should be:

```
"1.txt.bkup" which has content (xyz)  
"2.txt.bkup" which has content (xyz)  
"5.txt" which has content (xyz)  
"6.txt" which has content (xyz)  
"1.txt" which has content (abc)  
"2.txt" which has content (abc)
```

How can this be done?
Shyam

Comment: Reading documentation would have taken lesser time than posting the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
cd /d sourcefolder
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    if exist "destinationfolder\%%~a" (
        move /y "destinationfolder\%%~a" "destinationfolder\%%~a.bkup"
    )
    copy "%%~a" "destinationfolder\%%~a"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Ans what you suggested creates a backup of new files which are copied from source. But what i need is, if the same file already exists in the destination, then keep it as a copy(rename existing to .txt.bkup) and copy from source. Hope you got my question.

Comment: small help, now the dest folder has the backups. now I have to rename .txt.bkup to .txt and delete the actual .txt in the dest.
Ex: dest folder has:  
1.txt   
1.txt.bkup  
2.txt
  
In this case, 1.txt should be removed and 1.txt.bkup shud be renamed to 1.txt.
please suggest how this can be done.

Comment: that's just another line in the for-loop: `if exist "destinationfolder\%%~a.bkup" ( del "destinationfolder\%%~a.bckup" )`

Comment: @Endoro: 
dest folder has: 
1.txt 
1.txt.bkup 
2.txt
 
In this case, 1.txt should be removed and 1.txt.bkup shud be renamed to 1.txt. Hope you got my question. Your previous edit did not serve the purpose :( thanks for your effort :)

Comment: Hmm, if you want to remove `1.txt` from destfolder you need a second destfolder for that. Please explain again what is when to move. `dest folder has: 1.txt 1.txt.bkup 2.txt In this case, 1.txt should be removed and 1.txt.bkup shud be renamed to 1.txt.` -- and what about _sourcefolder 1.txt_ ?

Comment: @Endoro: I could make out where i was going wrong. Thanks for your time :)